# tabs are displaying in drawer but switch not happening

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am new to material ui.
- when you click advanced sports search a drawer opens up.
- i am trying to implement tabs in the drawer, but when I click the tab two in the drawer its closing.
- actually it should switch between tabs.
- its working on the intial page.
- so I debugged the handleChange method its working fine for inital page and printing console --->    console.log("switch tabs inital page--->");
- where as when I debug drawer tabs its  printing console but not switching tabs--->     console.log("switch tabs drager ui--->");
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/1qlpxx34v3

```
 handleChange = (event, value) => {
    console.log("switch tabs drager ui--->");
    this.setState({ value });
  };


  <Tabs
            value={value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            scrollable
            scrollButtons="on"
            indicatorColor="primary"
            textColor="primary"
          >
            <Tab label="Item One" icon={<PhoneIcon />} />
            <Tab label="Item Two" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} />

          </Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 222 in `tab-demo.js`, I commented out this line:

`onClick={this.toggleDrawer("right", false)}`

Because with that line, every time you click inside the drawer, it will close.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply. I updated the code but the problem is in the drawer tabs the content of second tab is also showing in first tab https://codesandbox.io/s/mzj2zp6y0p